# Are Homura's wings witch wings in the end?

Tags: madoka-magica

At the end of the anime where Homura is in a wasteland, she grows wings. The texture is almost the same as the art style that is used for witches and their lairs, so I'm wondering - at the end of the anime, was Homura becoming something of a witch/magical girl hybrid?

Pictures of Homura's wings:

[image: Homura's wings from the front, from the Blu-Ray]

[image: Homura's wings from the back, from the TV airing]

[image: Homura's wings from the side, from the movie]

Comment: Could you add a picture? I don't remember this at all...

Comment: @atlantiza It's at the very end, as i said she's in a wasteland and there is a large number of Wraith ahead of her, you hear her say something to Madoka and you hear Madoka's voice echo in reply before she walks off with a set of wrings growing out her back which ends the scene with them covering the entire screen, i'll post up a screen shot when i get at the DVDs again

Comment: @atlantiza I've added some screenshots.

Comment: @senshin where did the last one come from cause i just remember the second last one cause from what i remember the screen just gets covers in her wings, i don't remember her flying away

Comment: @Memor-X The shot of Homura flying appears in all three versions of the show (TV, Blu-Ray, movie).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Rebellion movie seems to hint that

> Homura's wings in this scene were indeed witch wings, or rather, the beginning of Homura's transformation into a witch.

The biggest clue is the landscape. The last time we see Homura in the series she is about to confront a bunch of wraiths in a desert landscape. The Rebellion movie reveals

> that the Incubators tried to trap Homura and interrupt her witch transformation in order to draw out Madoka. When the Incubators' barrier is broken, Homura is still in the desert.

If you assume the two deserted landscapes are one and the same,

> you would conclude that Homura was about to turn into a witch at the end of the series. Presumably, that's where her transformation began before it was interrupted, setting the events of the Rebellion movie in motion.

Answer (score 2):

There is no definitive answer as to what exactly Homura's wings are, at this time. It is possible that the third movie will reveal new information about the nature of her wings, but for now, there is no real answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

If the 3rd movie is anything to go by, these are demon wings. When Madoka is grasped and pulled in by Homura at the end of Rebellion, Homura rewrites the universe once again. Here, she dons a pair of black wings. When Kyubey asks who she is, Homura replies she is a demon. Thus, it is probably safe to conclude these are demon wings.